# recover the slug of a category linked to another category Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

**I would like to recover the slug of 2 categories from my routes but can’t** write the **Controller**.

**My Route**

```
Route::get('technicians/o/{occupation}/c/{city}', 'User\TechnicianController@viewoccupationcity');
```

**My Controller**

```
  public function viewoccupationcity($slug)
{

    $technicians = TechnicianResource::collection(occupation::where('slug',$slug)->firstOrFail()->technicians()
        ->with('city','occupation')
        ->latest()->get());
    return $technicians;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by slug?  the whole url slug or just the passed properties?

Comment: In effect as you can see i have 2 variables in my Route i want to recover their slug.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('technicians/o/{occupation}/c/{city}', 'User\TechnicianController@viewoccupationcity');
```

Your controller will accept the parameters from your route as variables by order

```
public function viewoccupationcity($ocupation, $city)
{
...
}
```

### Example:

```
URL: technicians/o/foo/c/bar


public function viewoccupationcity($ocupation, $city)
{
   // $ocupation will be 'foo'
   // $city will be 'bar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you would need to retrieve 2 variables as that is what you are passing

```
  public function viewoccupationcity($occupation, $city)
```

If you want the whole slug to do another search then you would use the $request object.  So like so

```
  public function viewoccupationcity(Request $request, $occupation, $city){ // You also need to include the Request decleration
$slug = $request->path();
 $technicians = TechnicianResource::collection(occupation::where('slug',$slug)->firstOrFail()->technicians()
        ->with('city','occupation')
        ->latest()->get());
    return $technicians;
}
```

EDIT: We are having to do a lot of guesswork as your question isn't very clear.  I think what you are trying to achieve is probably this

```
public function viewoccupationcity($occupation, $city){
 $technicians = TechnicianResource::collection(occupation::where('city',$city)->where('occupation',$occupation)->firstOrFail()->technicians()
        ->with('city','occupation')
        ->latest()->get());
    return $technicians;
}
```

If you need something more then you need to give more details

Comment: I tried but didn’t worked can you suggest something else please?

Comment: Thanks alot i used your method but it returned this error:  **Call to a member function technicians() on null**